# Sending emails to recipients if certain cell value is met by each receipient

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-macros

Basically I've used Google Sheets to create an invoice tracker, and I want to send a reminder email to each of my clients when their invoice is due. I've already set the date and the count down, and now I want to send them the reminder email when the cell value reaches "2" meaning 32 days has passed since I've invoiced them.

I've gathered the codes from different sources online, and also I've set a 24 hr trigger to run the code once in a day. The email template is also in place. Data of each client (dates, names, addresses, etc.) are listed in separate rows.

My problem is that instead of sending 1 single email to the right client, the mailing app sends emails to all clients when any of them have a due invoice!

I'm not sure which function or code I should use. 
I tried 'Email_Sent' thing, but couldn't get anywhere good with it!

```
function CheckMaturity() {
  // Fetch invoice maturity
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('InvoiceTracker').activate();   
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    for (var i = 5;i<=10;i++){
      var invoiceMaturityRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('InvoiceTracker').getRange(i, 13); 
      var invoiceMaturity = invoiceMaturityRange.getValue();
      // Check invoice maturity
        if (invoiceMaturity = 2){
        // Fetch the email address
          SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('InvoiceTracker').activate();

          var templateText = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('EmailTemplate').getRange(1,1).getValue();

          var currentAddress = ss.getRange(i, 15).getValue(); 
          var currentInvoiceNo = ss.getRange(i, 3).getValue(); 
          var currentInvoiceDate = ss.getRange(i, 4).getValue(); 
          var currentClient = ss.getRange(i, 14).getValue();
          var messageBody = templateText.replace('{client}',currentClient).replace('{invoiceNo}',currentInvoiceNo).replace('{invoiceDate}', currentInvoiceDate);
          var subjectLine = 'Kind reminder - Invoice status';

          MailApp.sendEmail(currentAddress, subjectLine, messageBody);{
          SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('Invoice reminder sent to' +currentClient, 'Reminder sent', -1);

          }

       }
    } 
}
```

I want the app to send only one single email to the right (relevant) client.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the below. Please check the variables and references. The following code should be adjusted. The column 'A' should be replaced with the column in which you have the last record to prevent that you miss any clients. Furthermore, please check the comments in the code below.

```
.Range("A1047854").End(xlUp).Row
```

And hereby the full code:

```
Sub SendEmails()
    Dim myOlApp As Outlook.Application, MailItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim attachmentPath1 As String, attachmentPath2 As String
    Set myOlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    'loop through a sheet (change index)
    For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets("index").Range("A1047854").End(xlUp).Row
        'set key for check (or just do it directly in the if)
        invoiceMaturity = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("index").Range("A" & i).Value
        If invoiceMaturity = "2" Then
            'you can load the variables first, before adding them to the email, or add them directly.
            Name = ""
            MailAddress = ""
            Address = ""
            currentInvoiceNo = ""
            currentInvoiceDate = ""
            currentClient = ""

            'make item for each iteration (again)
            Set MailItem = myOlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
            'attachments
            attachmentPath1 = "path/to/file.something" 'or set to ""(nothing)
            'body
            MailItem.HTMLBody = "<B>" & "<h3>" & "DRAFT:" & "</h3>" & "</B>" & "<br>" & _
                "Dear, " & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
                "Please find enclosed a kind reminder.." & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
                "Please note, that.." & "</b>" & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
                "Should you have any questions or comments on the above, please do let us know." & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
                "Kind regards," & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
                "Signature"

            MailItem.to = MailAddress  'adjust email
            MailItem.Subject = "[subject of email" & "a variable?" 'adjust subject
            MailItem.Show 'or mailitem.send

            'just to make sure
            Set MailItem = ""

        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help and support. Would that be possible for you to add something to my own codes, as this one you've suggested is a bit difficult for me to grasp and modify since I'm a beginner! :)